# BxSlider remove first 3 slides (divs)

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have a slideshow with 6 slides (divs) in it. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="SlideshowWrapper">
<div id="Slideshow" style="display: none;">
<div><a href="#"><img src="/images/image1.jpg" /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="/images/image2.jpg" /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="/images/image3.jpg" /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="/images/image4.jpg" /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="/images/image5.jpg" /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src="/images/image6.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#Slideshow > div").slice(0, 3).remove();
```

The code works fine [HERE IN THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YTBqe/). I think since I'm using a BxSlider slider, it prevents it from working. Anyone know a different method I can remove the first 3 slides (divs)?

Comment: if you want not to show the first 4 `div`s inside BxSlider, just don't use them in the HTML. Could you explain a bit more as to what you want in BxSlider ?

Comment: My end goal is to have only the last 3 slides show when the screen width is mobile size. The first 3 are for desktop, the last 3 are for mobile. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why do you really need to hide 3 `div`s completely in mobile view ? What's about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950077/change-number-of-slides-on-bxslider-depending-on-screensize ?

Comment: @ChristopherNorthcutt You can use `$("#myList > div:lt(3)").remove()` to removing target elements.

Comment: @Mohammad, if the same page works for both computer  and  mobile version, then resizing the window to a mobile screen size will remove the elements. So on stretching the window , how will the removed ones be added ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I writed solution for this question, it isn't solution for end goal of ChristopherNorthcutt

Comment: @ChristopherNorthcutt, do you want to view only the first 3 `div`s in computer version and the last 3 `div`s for the mobile version ? Do you have a mobile subdomain for the mobile version  or  do you want to show both computer and mobile version from the same domain ?

Comment: i just have one domain. Trying to swap out the URLs for the mobile version. I want different images to show for the mobile version

Comment: @ChristopherNorthcutt Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YTBqe/1/) your purpose?

Comment: mohammed, that doesnt work. Works in jsfiddle but when you use it with the bxslider it doesnt work. I've tried similar code like that already

Comment: @ChristopherNorthcutt Do you changed jquery selector in your html? You need to change selector relevant to your html.

Comment: I figured it out guys. I just made 2 seperate slide shows and hide/show them depending on the screen width. Thanks.